# AngularJS Replace array Objects

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I have an answers array that is prepopulated length based on a questions array

```
 $scope.length = parseInt($scope.questions.length);
     $scope.quizAnswers = [];
     for(var i = 0 ; i < parseInt($scope.length) ; i++)
          $scope.quizAnswers.push({id:i, Index:i,  Answered":"No","Correct":"null"});
```

I want the Objects in this answer array to be replaced by their Index value
based on the answer

```
quizAnswers: [{"id":0,"Index":0,"Answered":"No","Correct":"null"},{"id":1,"Index":1,"Answered":"No","Correct":"null"},{"id":3,"Index":3,"Answered":"No","Correct":"null"},{"id":0,"Index":2,"Answered":"Yes","Correct":"Correct"}]
```

So the final Object `{"id":0,"Index":2,"Answered":"Yes","Correct":"Correct"}`  needs to replace `{"id":2,"Index":2,"Answered":"No","Correct":"null"}`,  Is there a way of doing this with push or splice to array

Comment: possibly  may work using angular.extend or angular.merge has anyone got examples of this in a plunker, jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are based on index. so it means that you can access the value through its index

```
quizAnswers = [
      {"id":0,"Answered":"No","Correct":"null"},
      {"id":1,"Answered":"No","Correct":"null"},
      {"id":3,"Answered":"No","Correct":"null"},
      {"id":0,"Answered":"Yes","Correct":"Correct"}
];

quizAnswers[2] = {"id":2,"Answered":"Yes","Correct":"Correct"};
```

Comment: in my  array      quizAnswers: [{"id":0,"Index":0,"Answered":"No","correct":"?"},{"id":0,"Index":0,"Answered":"Yes","Correct":"Correct"},}]   the last value appended not replacing the first objects  , how do I splice  or replace on the array with   var newquizAnswer = {

                            id: param1,   
                            Index: param1,
                            Answered: 'Yes',
                            Correct: 'Correct'

                        };  $scope.quizAnswers.push(newquizAnswer);

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to have answers as an object rather than an array. You could then use the index as the key. eg:

```
quizAnswers = {
    "0": {"id":0,"Answered":"No","Correct":"null"},
    "1": {"id":1,"Answered":"No","Correct":"null"},
    "3": {"id":3,"Answered":"No","Correct":"null"},
    "2": {"id":0,"Answered":"Yes","Correct":"Correct"}
}
```

This would allow you to directly update the answers. eg:

```
quizAnswers["2"] = {"id":0,"Answered":"Yes","Correct":"Correct"};
```